# I'm getting the error Unexpected symbol 'void' in Unity after copying a code and I don't know why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error on my code that I was copying off youtube for a better jump. Could someone explain to me what is wrong with my code? It's below.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class jump : MonoBehaviour {

    public float FallMultiplier = 2.5f;
    public float lowJumpMultiplier = 2f;

    RigidBody2D rb;
    }

    void Awake() {
    rb = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();

    }

    void FixedUpdate() {

    if (rb.velocity.y < 0) {
    rb.velocity.y += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (FallMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    } else if (rb.velocity.y > 0 && !Input.GetButton("Space")) {
    rb.velocity.y += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (lowJumpMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }


    }
```

Comment: You might want to remove the `}` after `RigidBody2D rd;`

Comment: After I remove the } it says Unexpected symbol  'end-of-file'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You accidentally closed your class and have methods outside. Remove the `}` below the line with `RigidBody2D rb`. Additionally, you're missing the closing brace for `FixedUpdate()`.

Comment: After I remove the } it says Unexpected symbol 'end-of-file'

Comment: You're also missing one after the `FixedUpdate()` method.

Comment: void FixedUpdate() } {                      ?

Comment: No. In between the last two `}`. Please don't take this the wrong way, but you appear unclear on the basics of programing and would probably benefit greatly from going through the Java course on Codecademy (Java is very similar to C#). Blindly copying code can may seem quick now but when you have to question everything you do, you'll quickly find it inefficient.

Comment: I don't take that the wrong way at all, I'm a complete beginner and actually recently started the java course on Codeacademy. Thanks for the help, though. I also misread what you said about the closing brace.